# Gdal_translate and transparent rasters in PDF

Tags: raster, mapserver, gdal-translate, transparency-opacity, geospatial-pdf

I am trying to make an application that creates geospatial pdf's from my website, but I am encountering problems with Gdal_translate and transparency of rasters.

The setup that I am working up against is based on Mapserver, creating wms services. These services are created with image/png properties, and a predefined transparency.
I would like to be able to combine these wms serices on top of a basemap in a geospatial PDF, but when I combine the layers with Gdal_translate, the transparency on the individual layers are lost.

When I call the layers individually with Gdal I am quite sure the transparency is present, so I assume that the problem occurs in the process of making the overlays in Gdal.

Have anybody experimented with this usage of gdal_translate against Mapserver - and have succeded in creating transparent overlays from rasters?

Comment: Could you show the gdal_translate command that you are using now and gdalinfo from one image you are capturing from Mapserver with WMS GetMaps?

Comment: Hi again. I tried to find examples of PDF files with transparent raster layers. Can you show a link to one such?

Comment: I havent found any examples - it was an exploratory task i started trying to do it... I can post the commands for Gdal later today - however the server that i am working against uses a session system, which means that it times out - making the URL requests invalid.

Comment: It may mean that PDF does not have such support. I found documents about transparency of PDF vector layers but nothing about rasters. If layers come from the same WMS, can't you request them combined with &layers=layer1,layer2,layer3...?